# Purge varnish cache based on request header values

Tags: varnish, vcl, varnish-vcl, purge

I am caching multiple copies of an object based on certain header values in the request using vcl hash. How do I purge them all at once?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on assumption that you really want to purge as in `PURGE`and not `BAN`:

In case all the possible values of the certain header are known, you would use restarts coupled with setting custom header. Logic is the following:

1. received `PURGE` request for object with `req.http.X-Custom == foo`
2. `return(purge)`
3. in `vcl_purge`, set `req.http.X-Custom = bar`, and introduce / adjust helper header with the set of values already purged, and `return (restart)`

As a result, Varnish will recursively purge all the objects.

You can see example of this approach in [complete Brotli VCL implementation](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/varnish-brotli-done-right).

But in case the values of the certain header are really arbitrary, you can't really `PURGE` them all at once. If you need this, you have to make use of `Vary: X-Custom` so that Varnish will consider all those objects as one with many variations. With `Vary` in place, you don't have to hash on the header and `PURGE` on one variation will effectively clear out all other variations.

I like `Vary` approach much better.